# How can i update just the label on the uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, label, refresh, reload

I just wan to update the label on the uitableviewcell without reloading the whole cell which containing images . How can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a custom UITableViewCell for the cell
   holding the UILabel
2. Set the class for the cell to your custom UITableViewCell in the storyboard inspector
3. Create an IBOutlet from your UILabel to the custom UITableViewCell
4. Access your label as so:

   (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomeTableViewCell).label.text = "Hello"

Comment: @KZY no worries :)